# Update the value changed in directive to controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

Usually, sequence of execution is controller ---> directive, right!
I have a scenario,

In the controller we have the default value of placeholder:

```
           $scope.formsDropDown = {
                    show: true,
                    placeholder: 'Select a Form',

            };
```

where in the directive I have a value of placeholder which is getting updated e.g.

```
   return {
            restrict: 'A',
            transclude: 'true',
            templateUrl: 'js/application/alpha.html',
            link: function ($scope) {
                  $scope.formsDropDown.placeholder = "ABC" ;
          }
```

**Issue**: Placeholder value is not getting updated hence taking the default value 'Select a Form'.

Can anybody please help me in this? I am stuck over here! *Suggestion would be really appreciated.* 
*Thanks!*

Comment: how you are updating in directive ..?

Comment: link: function ($scope) {$scope.formsDropDown.placeholder = "ABC" ; }

Comment: can you add the html of directive?

Comment: and also the use of that directive?

Answer (score 0):

Try attribute param of link function to set placeholder value.

```
         return {
                restrict: 'A',
                transclude: 'true',
                templateUrl: 'js/application/alpha.html',
                link: function ($scope, elem,  attrs) {
                     // $scope.formsDropDown.placeholder = "ABC" ;
                     attrs.$set('placeholder','ABC');
              }
          }
```